# MySQL select from to involved tables

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have two tables. 
One table looks like: user(id, username)
The other Table looks like: rating(user_id, rating)

Now i want to select the find the top 10 rated users with:

```
SELECT *
FROM rating order by rating
LIMIT 10;
```

now i want to "switch" to the username and show the usernames from the top 10 ids.

How I could do that?

Comment: check there question seems like you have misplaced persons in place of users in the query. also you need to perform join of user and rating to get the desired result

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT u.username,r.rating
FROM user u
INNER JOIN rating r ON u.id = r.user_id
ORDER BY r.rating DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.username, r.rating
FROM rating as r, user as u 
WHERE r.user_id = u.id 
ORDER BY r.rating DESC 
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: It is more easy way. Or use INNER JOIN.

Comment: inner join is the easiest way

Comment: I'm not convinced that SO should be promoting a join syntax that went out with the last ice age.

Answer (score 0):

try this query

SELECT user.username, rating.rating
    FROM user
    LEFT JOIN rating ON user.id = rating.user_id
    ORDER BY rating.rating DESC
    LIMIT 10;

Comment: Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long but it is expected.